# VSCode debug C# _ How to prevent opening internal debug console

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

When I debug my C# code I don't want to open internal debug console (My setting in ".vscode/launch.json" is: "console": "externalTerminal"), I need only external console:

[image]

I've disabled debug console:

[image]

but debug console still reveals.

Please help to prevent revealing debug console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. you need to do 2 things:

1. into first object of ".vscode/launch.json":

"console": "externalTerminal",
"internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",

2. into array, first object of ".vscode/tasks.json":

"presentation": {
"reveal": "never"
}

Answer (score 2):

You should add a setting in `launch.json`.
Add `"internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"`, then the debug console won't appear again.

Comment: thanks but terminal still reveals: https://i.imgur.com/mPmpYnq.png
@ride_pig

Comment: You just mentioned that you don't want the debug console to reveal in your question. If you also don't want to see the terminal, then you should edit a sub setting in `tasks.json`. Add `"presentation"` to "build" task (maybe more than one task, you can distinguish every task by "label" of it) of `"tasks.json"`, and vscode will generate a list of sub settings, then change the value of `"reveal"` into `"never"` or `"slient"` ( which I recommend because this makes the vscode to remind you if there're any problem). After doing this, the terminal won't reveal again.